# BackupPC jobs hanging

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I have a separate Ubuntu 10 server running BackupPC, which uses rsync to get backups from 9 other Ubuntu 10 servers.

It is scheduled to get a full backup once a week, and do incrementals every night. It has been working like clockwork for over a year.

However, since about 2 weeks ago, I began experiencing issues with one of the servers. All automatic and manual backups begin execution, but hang during the process. Meaning, they show up in the current jobs, and in the host summary they are listed as "in progress." They sit in that state until they are manually cancelled. There is absolutely nothing in the error logs on the backup server or the client. Credentials or any settings have not changed. The space on the server is also sufficient. I've rebooted both servers.

What could be the reason for a backup job simply hanging without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

What does the [logfile](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/backuppc/index.php?title=How_to_view_log_file_for_running_backup) say about the running backup? Are you tunneling over ssh? Have you made firewall changes? Is sshd/rsyncd running on the client?